# Is the cinema from Adaline real?

Tags: film-location, the-age-of-adaline

In the movie *Age of Adaline*, the main character takes Ellis on a date to an old warehouse in San Francisco, which used to be a drive-in cinema in the 30s. She tells a story about it and shows how unique the roof of the warehouse is.

Is this cinema based on something real, is some part of this story based on true events? Or is it completely made up for the movie?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1655441/locations ?

Comment: @BCdotWEB there is no mention of this scene in that link.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the theater was real in the age of Adaline.

Comment: Hi! As of now, it looks like a comment. Can you add any credible sources to back your answer?